# Laravel - View with multiple attributes, URL only with ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I'm trying to give attributes to a view (So i can use them in blade) while in the route it only requires the ID. let me explain

The route I'm talking about is `Route::get('/order/{id}', 'OrderController@show');` now in that particular show method, I want to return a view with the `$order` variable another variable called `$payment` which consists of some information. So that I can use them in blade. Thats show method looks like this

```
public function show(Order $order, $payment)
{
    return view('orders.show', compact('order', 'payment'));
}
```

In that same controller I have a store method and when everything inside that method is executed it redirects to the show method by doing this

`return $this->show($order, $payment);`

But when the store method is executed and the order is shown. The URL is `order/26/store` instead of `order/26`. presumably because I use

`return view('orders.show', compact('order', 'payment'));` in the show method.

How can I make it so I can use both the variables (In blade) while the route looks like 'order/26' Instead of `order/26/store`

Both routes I'm talking about are listed here.

```
Route::get('/order/{id}/store', 'OrderController@store')->name('storeOrder');
Route::get('/order/{id}', 'OrderController@show')->name('showConfirm');
```

Comment: I might be stupid, but removing the `/store` from `Route::get('/order/{id}/store', 'OrderController@store')->name('storeOrder');` do the trick? But make sure to rename `/order/{id}` from `Route::get('/order/{id}', 'OrderController@show')->name('showConfirm');` to something else e.g. `/order/confirmation/{id}`?

Comment: Which is your Laravel version?

Answer (score 2):

If you were created controller with --resources. Laravel makes all routes byself. After creating smt with store function it redirect show/{id}

In the store function you must specify the route.

Store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $order = Order::all();

    return redirect()->route('order.show', $order->id);
}
```

Function show

```
public function show($id)
{


    return view('order.show');
}
```